# Pandoc - Insert separator between files

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I am trying to use pandoc to merge a bunch of markdown files into a single html document. Each file is for a different class lecture, and my goal is to have a `<hr>` tag inserted between each markdown file, so it is easier to see where the lecture breaks occur.

I know it is possible to add the breaks manually, or style the html such that each new header tag also has a rule, but I would like to learn how to do this with just pandoc.

My current command looks like:

`pandoc *.md > output.html`

I have tried using the `-A` flag, but that inserts something after the ENTIRE body, whereas I want to insert a rule between each markdown document.

I realize that this may not be possible (if pandoc concatenates before processing), and in that case, I can just preprocess/concat the files with another script.

To summarize, I want a way to do

```
[01.md]
<hr>
[02.md]
<hr>
...
[last.md]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what I was hoping for, but I realized I can use `gnu-sed` to just add the separators to the markdown document before concatenating to make pandoc insert the `<hr>` tags.

The extra newlines are to make sure the separator is on its own line and the md file ends with a newline so pandoc works properly

```
sed -s '$a\\n----\n' *.md | pandoc -f markdown > output.html
```

Solution from a previous [superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/103530/how-can-one-join-files-with-seperating-data-in-bash)

Note: for OSX you need to do `brew install gnu-sed` and use `gsed` instead of `sed`